# Confusing JavaScript object behaviour

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I’m using Socket.IO with Node.js.

I have an object `socket` which looks like this:

```
SocketNamespace
    $events: Object
    ...
    socket: Socket
```

So then If I look at `Socket` (i.e. `socket.socket`)

```
Socket
    $events: Object
    ...
    sessionid: "1549988601982716407"
```

Again, works fine.

But if I just want to return `sessionid`, so I use `socket.socket.sessionid` I get...

```
undefined
```

If I do a `typeof` for `socket.socket` I get `object`, but for `socket.socket.sessionid`, I just get `undefined`.

---

**Edit:** here’s my code:

Browser:

```
$(function() {

    $.getScript('http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js', function() {
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
        console.log(socket.socket.sessionid);
    });

});
```

App:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

});
```

---

**Edit 2:** More data:

Instead of the one log, I’ve replace with this;

```
console.log(typeof(socket));
console.log(typeof(socket.socket));
console.log(typeof(socket.socket.sessionid));
```

Returns:

```
object
object
undefined
```

Expected:

```
object
object
string
```

---

**Edit 3:*** Screenshot

[image: Screenshot of console]

---

**Edit 4**

This, oddly, works.

```
var x;
for (x in socket.socket)
{
    if (x == 'sessionid') {
        console.log(socket.socket[x]);
    }
}
```

Comment: ***Please*** don't quote pseudo-code. Your problem is likely down to the *actual code you use*. We can't help you if you don't quote the actual code.

Comment: I’ve added the code – but it’s just standard stuff, didn’t see the need to fill up the page with code.

Comment: So in your original sample you reference `sessionid`, but in your edited code you cite `session_id`. Could this be the problem? Should it be `sessionid`?

Comment: Sorry no I’d accidentally typed it when typing the console.log back in for the test code. I’ve just tested it again and it’s still doing what it did before.

Comment: @ThomasEdwards: The code's no longer than the pseudo-code, and much more precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can’t believe this.

```
socket.socket['sessionid']
```

That worked. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

`socket.socket.sessionid` is indeed valid and contains the session id once it's set. The problem is it's not set at the moment you print it to the console, since the socket hasn't made a connection yet (and thus doesn't have a session id).

Change the lines

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
console.log(socket.socket.sessionid);
```

to

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
socket.on('connect', function () {
    console.log(socket.socket.sessionid);
});
```

and everything should be golden.

Comment: Sadly that hasn’t worked for me – still sends `undefined`. Thanks for your input, that does make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain WHY the error occured in the first place.

The TC, was looking at Chrome dev console and it was showing some data. 
But

```
console.log(typeof(socket));
```

and

```
console.log(typeof(socket.socket.sessionid));
```

**do not** produce equal output.

If you look at Chrome console, you will see a small "i" symbol near the object.

This means, that when you try to access sessionid it doesn't actually have it. 
Try e.g. with open property. You will see that it shows something different from the object output.

But when you **click** it in a console, it produces it on the fly.

If you need a working code, it looks like this:

```
// SERVER. Place it where you first _receive_ a connection from a client.
socket.emit('connected'); 
// This will emit connected message. 
//It is a signal to your client, that there is an established CLIENT<->SERVER connetion

// CLIENT
socket.on('connected', function (){
console.log(socket.socket.sessionid);} // This produces correct sessionid
```

Now, this will produce a valid sessionid on a client side.

As you see, in your example you simply try to access a not-yet existing property. 
A couple of milliseconds too fast ;)

I hope that is clear now.